# Controlling data in a listbox with a combobox

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I am attempting to change a value in a a list box using a combobox.

My combobox datasource is a bindingsource that has as its datasource a keyvaluepair collection of states. The Key is the State abbreviation, the value is a State Class holding the relevant information about the state.
My listbox has as its datasource a bindingsource that has as its datasource a list of records which also contain a State value.

When the user clicks on an item in the listbox, I want the value in the combobox to reflect what is in the selecteditems State value. Then if I change that value I want the listbox item to be updated.
Currently I can get the Combobox to load correctly, and I can get the Listbox loading correctly. Using the below code, When i change between items in the listbox, the combobox does not update; but if I change the value in the combobox the listitem changes and the value will continue repopulate if I move off the record and back on. But when I move to an item that I have not edited the combobox text goes blank again.  Below is my code. How do I need to change my bindings so that:

- When I selected in the listbox, the items State appears correctly in the combobox
- When the value is changed in the combobox, the State is changed in the listbox

XML file that is the Datasource for the Listbox Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConversionRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ConversionRecord>
    <InboundOriginCity>Seaford 0</InboundOriginCity>
    <InboundOriginState>
      <Key>AS</Key>
      <PostalAbbreviation>AS</PostalAbbreviation>
    </InboundOriginState>
    <InboundDestinationCity>Salisbury 0</InboundDestinationCity>
    <InboundDestinationState>
      <Key>AS</Key>
      <PostalAbbreviation>AS</PostalAbbreviation>
    </InboundDestinationState>
    <InboundCommodity>000000</InboundCommodity>
  </ConversionRecord>
  <ConversionRecord>
    <InboundOriginCity>Seaford 1</InboundOriginCity>
    <InboundOriginState>
      <Key>AS</Key>
      <PostalAbbreviation>AS</PostalAbbreviation>
    </InboundOriginState>
    <InboundDestinationCity>Salisbury 1</InboundDestinationCity>
    <InboundDestinationState>
      <Key>AS</Key>
      <PostalAbbreviation>AS</PostalAbbreviation>
    </InboundDestinationState>
    <InboundCommodity>111111</InboundCommodity>
  </ConversionRecord>
</ConversionRecords>
```

My attempted Databindings:

```
_FileBindingSource = New BindingSource(_recordsRepository.getConversionRecords(), Nothing)
_InboundOriginStateBindingSource = New BindingSource(_stateRepository.StatesByKey, Nothing)
_InboundDestinationStateBindingSource = New BindingSource(_stateRepository.StatesByKey, Nothing)

ListBox1.DataSource = _FileBindingSource

'cboInboundOriginState
cboInboundOriginState.DisplayMember = "Key"
cboInboundOriginState.ValueMember = "Value"
cboInboundOriginState.DataSource = _InboundOriginStateBindingSource
cboInboundOriginState.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", _FileBindingSource, "InboundOriginState", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through much research I found the answer. In order for this to work I had to override Equals(objA as object) as boolean. Once I did this comparing the values that are unique for that class it worked.